# How to send/receive image in wordpress web services

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, image-uploading, request.querystring

I just wrote web services for wordpress like login, register, pass update, etc...

Now I want to user can upload images from iOS device and send this via web services(query string). I am not sure how to do this.

For login I just create a query string like `http://example.com/apps/login.php?user=something&pass=something` and get all the data in php file and then update the wordpress DB and return success message in json_encode.

But for images, how I can create the query string and how I can get those images in php file.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

> But for images, how I can create the query string

You **DO NOT**! It's not a place for that. If you need data uploaded, do it right way using HTTP POST request with data payload.

Comment: You mean I need to give PHP file action for form?

Comment: You seem to lack basics. POST it's not for forms (forms can use GET). Is a way of sending bigger payloads. Used with forms too. And yes, use POST from your app to your backend PHP script